# React Redux fire action during routing change

Tags: reactjs, redux, router

I am using "react-router": "^4.1.1", and I was able to make it work successfuly in my project. Now i need to fire and action when the routing changes. How can I do it?

/*index.js*/

```
render((
    <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <HeaderContainer />
        <Main />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>


    </Provider>),

  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

/*Main.js*/

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
              <main>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
                  <Route path='/subMenu' component={subMenu}/>
                  <Route path='/Dummy' component={Dummy}/>
                </Switch>
              </main>
            );
        }
    }

export default Main;
```

/*component/product.js*/

```
const Product = ({ ImageUrl, price, quantity, Title, ID }) => (

    <div className="grid_item menuCategoryList_item">
      <Link to='/subMenu' data-productid= {ID} data-id="menuOrderModal" className="js-openModalOverlay">
        {<div className="menuCategoryList_photo"><img src={ImageUrl} alt=""/></div>}
      </Link>
    </div>

)
```

Now an action fired is caught by my reducer and that takes care of populating data. How can I fire an action when routing happens?

Comment: Was there more to your question?

"How can I fire an action when..."

Comment: You can make use of 'render' or 'children' methods of Route instead of the 'component'. For example: 

<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => {
  doSomething();
  return <Menu />;
}}/>

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: I was on vacation sorry.

Comment: so according to your answer will my MAin.js look something like this?   
 class Main extends React.Component {

 <main>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => { doSomething(); return <Menu />; }}/>
       <Route path='/subMenu' component={subMenu}/>
       <Route path='/Dummy' component={Dummy}/>
     </Switch>
   </main>
 );



export default Main;

Answer (score 0):

Generally there are 2 ways:

1)Inside component

```
 import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

  //Your initialization

  browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
   //Do your stuff here
  });
```

2)In your root component

```
  <Route path="/" onChange={yourHandler} component={AppContainer}>
     <IndexRoute component={StaticContainer}  />
     <Route path="/a" component={ContainerA}  />
     <Route path="/b" component={ContainerB}  />
   </Route>

  function yourHandler(previousRoute, nextRoute) {
     //do your logic here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, But "react-router": "^4.1.1", does not support onChange anymore